# Touch Bar stopped working after water damage

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-bar, damage

I have a MacBook Pro (13", 2018) with a touch bar. I accidentally dropped a bit of water on my touch bar and it stopped working. It's been that way for a while now.

I tried opening the activity monitor to see if it pops up like how it does for the others, but nothing related to the touch bar is appearing to me. However, the fingerprint sensor still works.

How can I make the rest of the touch bar function again?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you'll need an SMC/NVRAM reset.

1. Shut Down your Mac and unplug everything.
2. On your built-in keyboard, press and hold all of the following keys. Your Mac might turn on.

   - Control  on the left side of your keyboard
   - Option (Alt)  on the left side of your keyboard
   - Shift  on the right side of your keyboard
3. Keep holding all three keys for 7 seconds, then press and hold the power button as well. If your Mac is on, it will turn off as you hold the keys.
4. Keep holding all four keys for another 7 seconds, then release them.
5. Wait a few seconds, then press the power button to turn on your Mac.

If this still doesn't work, shut down your Mac, then turn it on and immediately press and hold these four keys together: Option, Command, P, and R.

You can release the keys after the Apple logo appears and disappears for the second time.

If ALL of that doesn't work, probably go to an Apple store (assuming they're still open where you live).

Sources:

- [Reset the NVRAM or PRAM of your Mac - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)
- [How to reset the SMC of your Mac - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

Comment: Can you please expand on what resetting the Power Control Module (system management controller) has to do with the Touch Bar?

Comment: I probably should have explained this in my answer, but the SMC in 2018 and onward MacBooks has been integrated into the T2 Chip (https://veertu.com/t2-in-new-mac-hardware-and-its-impact-on-virtualizing-and-running-macos-role-of-smc/) which also serves as the "CPU" of the Touch Bar (https://www.idownloadblog.com/2020/03/10/luca-todesco-teases-checkra1n-hacks-on-a-t2-equipped-macbook-pros-touch-bar/). By resetting the management controller of the Touch Bar, it may resolve the issue.